# Cluster Heriarchal Plot en Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, cluster

Estoy empezando hacer un análisis de tipo cluster jerárquico utilizando Python.

Llego a una salida (Gráfico abajo), pero las etiquetas de las especies son muy grandes y no se dejan ver correctamente.
estoy intentando separar los cantos de las especies registradas (sapos y ranas) según el tiempo empleado en cantar.

Les dejo el código con el que estoy trabajando. Abajo mis datos (tabla).

Soy muy nuevo en Python:

```
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as shc

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.title("Calling Events Dendrogram")

clusters = shc.linkage(tabla, 
            method='ward', 
            metric="euclidean")
shc.dendrogram(Z=clusters)

plt.show()
```

Si alguien de este ciberespacio puede ayudarme estaré eternamente agradecido!

les dejo mis datos (tabla)

[tabla de datos](https://file:///C:/Users/Martin/Desktop/Trabajo/DatosSitiosCalilegua/Cluster_Analisis/Cluster%20Analysis/tablasitios.txt)

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). La variable `tabla` no existe así que no se puede reproducir tu problema

Comment: Por otra parte, por favor agrega y/o explica lo que has intentado hacer para obtener la gráfica como la deseas.

Comment: gracias por la ayuda @HeytalePazguato voy a editar mi pregunta.